# What is the cost of magic armor over the cost of mundane armor?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, pricing

In my current campaign the DM is allowing us to use a pricing chart to buy magic items. The cost of a +1 Armor is listed as 1,500gp.
For example, plate armor in the PHB is listed as 1,500gp.
In order to buy +1 plate armor would the cost be 3,000gp (plate armor cost plus premium cost for +1 armor) or does +1 armor cost 1,500gp just as plate armor does?

Assume I do not already own plate armor.

Even if we did not use this chart the DMG has a price range for rarity level.
Would we add that price, based on rarity level, to the plate armor's cost to arrive at a final cost, or is the DMG cost the total sum?

This question applies to all types of armor and weapons in the same situation. (+1 weapon is 1,000gp on the chart)

Comment: Related: [How much does Plate Armor of Gleaming cost?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/132090/33707)

Comment: @Sdjz Yes, that is related but sadly doesn't answer this specific question.

Comment: So has your DM provided this chart or are you building a chart, if the latter has the DM provided guidelines on availability of magic, difficulty in creating said item or any other factors that would affect this chart?

Comment: @Slagmoth The Dm has provided the chart.

Comment: The DM has provided a chart he found online for the prices of each individual magic item and stated that we can purchase any of the items in the city as long as we have the gold.

Comment: If you can provide the chart here, or an example of the chart, I'm sure we can get a more specific answer sorted for you, without it, NautArch has the most apt answer, "Ask your DM".

Comment: As currently written it’s unclear what these prices mean because we don’t have the chart or know who made it, or what it’s based on. I’ve voted to hold as “unclear” until the list itself is identified enough in the post to answer questions about it.

Comment: On the off-chance this is the "Sane Magic Item Prices" chart from the oots forum, it says "All items which are weapons or armor add the cost of the base weapon or armor that makes them up to their price." http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?424243-Sane-Magic-Item-Prices

Comment: I hope you do not mind the edit, I felt it needed a little more specificity.  Please ask for the link to the on line pricing chart, and add the link to the question, so that prospective answers have something to work from.  If @falsedot is correct in their guess, please advice.

Comment: @NautArch It’s true, and that’s still a valid answer, but right now this is just fodder for less disciplined answer-writers to start guessing. Knowing more about the chart is necessary to shut down guesses, though the best answer might still be “ask your DM.” At the very least though, then answers could explain what the chart is for, even if they also note that the DM might be going off the road.

Comment: @falsedot Of course the *All items which are weapons or armor add the cost of the base weapon or armor that makes them up to their price isn't on the chart that has +1 armor(which he segregated out due to bounded accuracy?)* but I think it would apply to armor since it is a combat item.

Comment: I do not have a link to the chart. He sent the PDF to us and I do not know how to provide the PDF on here.

Comment: @falsedot I believe the chart you referenced is the chart my DM provided. The wording to what you quoted is unclear to me.

Comment: @NautArch The DM is using the chart in its entirety. The only change he made was to double all prices except when bought from a specific merchant.

Comment: You could type in the relevant data from the chart, or possibly upload it to somewhere like Google Drive and give us the link there

Comment: You need to figure out how to tell us clearly what it is, if you want to ask a question about it. Maybe ask your DM where it came from.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I don't find a name for it but I believe it is the one falsedot posted in his comment.

Comment: As usual, by “tell us clearly” I mean in the question. If you’re sure that’s it, then edit the question to be about it. (If you’re not sure, figure out how to get sure.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I don't know how to add that into the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Ask your DM

In this case, the DM is coming up with a system for pricing. We really have no idea what that system is and you need to discuss it with them and work out the kinks and interactions you're interested in.

### DMG pricing

The DMG (page 135) has a chart for pricing ranges across the various levels of rarity for magic items.

> If your campaign allows for trade in magic items, rarity can also help you set prices for them. As the DM, you determine the value of an individual magic item based on its rarity. Suggested values are provided in the Magic Item Rarity table. The value of a consumable item, such as a potion or scroll, is typically half the value of a permanent item of the same rarity.
>
> Unless you decide your campaign works otherwise, most magic items are so rare that they aren’t available for purchase. Common items, such as a potion of healing, can be procured from an alchemist, herbalist, or spellcaster. Doing so is rarely as simple as walking into a shop and selecting an item from a shelf. The seller might ask for a service, rather than coin.

The pricing ranges are the prices for those items, it doesn't say that they are in addition to the mundane cost for that type of item. The DMG just provides the range for that item.

### More optional guidance in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*

Chapter 2 of this book has some additional pricing options. These are likely all-inclusive because there is no language of "add this cost on top of the mundane price for the item."